# How can I get mutiple url bitmap with asynctask

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

Well I want to download many of bitmap files with Asynctask.
(This bitmap is located on the network)

If then what should do I do for this job?

```
private ArrayList<String> bitmapUrls;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitarray;
```

..
`bitmapUrls.add("Here's my bitmap url");`
x 10
..

```
public class DownloadImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        for(String biturl:bitmapUrls){
            bitmap = downloadBitmap(biturl);
            return bitmap;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bitarray.add(result);
    }

    public Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient
                .newInstance("Android");
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode
                        + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
                return null;
            }

            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeStream(inputStream);


                    return bitmap;
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            getRequest.abort();
        } finally {
            if (client != null) {
                client.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

As you see I really want to get bitarray result array in my code.
Please give me an advice for improving this stuff code.

Comment: Check out : https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: You can use multiple `AsyncTask` to do, each of your task handle one url to download. Or other concurrent method in Java, `ExecutorService`, `ThreadPoolExecutor`.